# Reading TCP stream with PHP (converting C# code)

Tags: c#, php, tcp, stream, client

I'm having problems getting/reading any response from a TCP server.
The connection is establishing fine and I'm writing to the server OK but there could be an issue with the particular EOT character required by this server (0x04).

Also the example code I've been given (see below - in C#) converts the string to binary/bytes, which from what I've read PHP doesn't require when using fsockopen & fputs.

**My code:**

```
$host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$port = 23432;
$msg = "sample message". chr(4);
$fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    $lines = "Error: could not open socket connection";
} else {
    // write the user string to the socket 
    fputs ($fp, $msg);

    // get the result 
    $lines .= fgets($fp, 1024);

    // close the connection 
    fclose($fp);
} ?>
Server said: <b><?php echo $lines; ?>
```

**The example C# code I was given:**

```
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(); 
tcp.Connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 23432); 
Console.WriteLine(); 
Console.WriteLine("Connected to tcp server."); 

// Sent request to tcp server 
NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream(); 
// Ask for travel time data 
byte[] tx = GetBytes("sample message"); 
stream.Write(tx, 0, tx.Length); 

// Receive data from tcp server 
byte[] buffer = new byte[0xffff]; 
int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 0xffff); 
Console.WriteLine("Received " + bytesRead + " bytes from tcp server"); 
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
Console.WriteLine("Below is the data received."); 
Console.WriteLine(s); 

// Keep the connection open, the data is coming every 20 secs 

tcp.Close(); 



// This function will add the binary byte (0x04) to the end of the text 
static private byte[] GetBytes(string str) 
{ 
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length + 1]; 
        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length, bytes, 0); 
        bytes[str.Length] = 0x04; 

        return bytes; 
}
```

Any ideas? At the moment the PHP code sits there for about 40 seconds after sending the message and returns nothing.

Comment: You can use a program such as Wireshark to check whats being sent/received by the C# code, and compare it to what's being sent/received by your PHP code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you converting the C# to PHP

Comment: I don't see `$lines` defined before hand; does it go out of scope by the time you print something from the server?